# How do I update a nested object in mongo only if that property exists?

Tags: mongodb

With a collection like:

```
{
_id: 1,
obj: {val1: 1, val3: 3}
},
{
_id: 2,
obj: {val2: 2, val3: 3}
}
```

can I update only the existing values in the obj in on query like

```
col.updateMany({ _id: { $in: [1, 2] } }, { $set: { val1: 12, val2: 22, val3: 32 } })
```

but I want the result to be

```
{
_id: 1
obj: {val1: 12, val3: 32 }
},
{
_id: 2
obj: {val2: 22, val3: 32}
}
```

I guess I am looking for a $setIfExists option.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- you can use a pipeline update to do a conditional update, requires MongoDB >=4.2
- instead of `12,22,32` put any values for `val1,val2,val3`
- it checks first if the value exists, and if exists update it with new value, else `$REMOVE` (it means add+remove = add nothing)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251a695f7e3c64c6511e16e)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$in": [1,2]}},
[{"$set": 
  {"obj.val1": 
   {"$cond": 
    [{"$ne": [{"$type": "$obj.val1"}, "missing"]}, 12, "$$REMOVE"]},
   "obj.val2": 
    {"$cond": 
     [{"$ne": [{"$type": "$obj.val2"}, "missing"]}, 22, "$$REMOVE"]},
    "obj.val3": 
     {"$cond": 
      [{"$ne": [{"$type": "$obj.val3"}, "missing"]}, 32, "$$REMOVE"]}}}],
{"multi": true})
```